# Where do methods "live?"

Tags: java

If each object has a different copy of instance variables, where do methods "live?"

As an example:

```
class A {
    public foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public foo() {
        System.out.println("foofoo");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        a.foo(); // "foofoo"
    }
}
```

I know that "foofoo" is printed. So are the methods bound to the objects or something?

Comment: Because of the similarity to a question I've asked in a different language I'm going to link my question here.  The difference between flash and java is that flash is a prototype based language which can have method overriding happening at runtime which is why my question is different. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783256/as2-are-functions-declared-in-a-class-stored-as-separate-instances-taking-up-mor

Comment: Since the economic downtown, a significant slice of methods has left its usual tables for something less glamorous, virtual vtables

Answer (score 4):

The process you are referring to is called *dynamic dispatch*.  The way that this is typically implemented is through virtual tables (often called vtables):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_table

A simple summary of how vtables work is that each method is stored at some memory address, and a vtable stores those addresses.  Using your example, `A` has a vtable with an entry that holds the memory address of its version of `foo`, while the subclass `B` has its own vtable with the same layout, but it instead holds the memory address of its own `foo`.

Answer (score 3):

This is generally an implementation issue. All you need to concern yourself with as a Java programmer is that each class can have different methods from other classes.

In terms of implementation (if you're interested in under-the-covers behaviour), the easiest solution would be for each class to have a pointer to all the relevant functions.

That way, when you extend `A` with `B`, an instance of type `B` will get all of `A`'s pointers to methods but with the `foo` method pointer pointing to `B`'s code.

A graphical representation where `B` extends `A`, overriding just `foo`:

```
class A
    foo ----------> Afoo code
    bar ----+-----> Abar code
class B     |
    bar ----+
    foo ----------> Bfoo code
```

Instances of a class (objects) know about their type so you can get easily from object `b` to class `B`. From there, it's a simple operation to find the correct code to run.